# Does PhantomJS support cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies, phantomjs

Does [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/) support cookies? If yes, where can I find the API details?

I am not able to figure it out after searching for a while now.

Comment: yes it supports cookie like browsers, what do you mean by API?

Comment: How do I get the value of a cookie? document.cookie does not seems to get anything at all.

Comment: document.cookie works in all browsers except in phontomjs, seems to be some bug, there are plans to add native API http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=354&start=100

Answer (score 45):

Yes, as of [1.7](http://phantomjs.org/release-1.7.html) Phantom has complete cookie handling, enabled by default.  Cookies are retained for the duration of the process's life.

If you'd like to retain cookies across runs of Phantom, there's a [command-line option `cookies-file`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference) where you can specify where to store persistent cookies.

> `--cookies-file=/path/to/cookies.txt` specifies the file name to store the persistent cookies.

In page script, you can use the regular `document.cookie` property.  Like in browsers, this property returns a string similar to that which would be sent in the `Cookie:` HTTP header.

In Phantom script, you can access cookies for a page (subject to the usual origin restrictions) via `page.cookies`, which returns **objects**.

You can also access *all* cookies (from all domains) using `phantom.cookies`.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://example.com', function (status) {
    page.evaluate(function() {
        document.cookie; // => "test=test-value;"
    });
    page.cookies; // => [{
                  //   domain: "example.com",
                  //   expires: "Wed, 08 Jan 2014 00:00:00 GMT"
                  //   httponly: false,
                  //   name: "test",
                  //   path: "/",
                  //   secure: false,
                  //   value: "test-value"
                  // }]
    phantom.cookies; // contains ALL cookies in Phantom's jar
});
```

To [add/edit/delete cookies](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-cookie), use the `addCookie`, `deleteCookie`, and `clearCookies` methods of either a `WebPage` object or the `phantom` object.

When you use the methods of a `WebPage` object, you only modify the cookies that are visible to the page.  Access to other domains is blocked.

However, using `phantom`'s cookie methods allow access to *all* cookies.  `phantom.addCookie` requires a domain (`WebPage.addCookie` assumes the current domain if you don't specify one), and `phantom.deleteCookie` deletes **any** cookie matching the specified name.

Comment: Except that when I do `console.log(document.cookie);` the execution just halts.

Comment: Doesn't hang for me on windows when used with a jasmine unit test... but Phantom does return undefined.

Comment: @Niyaz: Cookies have been fixed in 1.7, and `document.cookie` works now.  See edits.

Comment: +1 for phantom.addCookie/deleteCookie, that this works across domains saves a lot of hassle

Comment: Note that the command-line option does not currently work in 2.x due to [a bug](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13115).

Comment: I needed to set cookies-file in order to use a script inside another script.

Comment: How do you add phantomjs so that phantom variable is visible to the scope, I get: "cannot find name phantom"

Answer (score 13):

It does, through [WebPage.addCookie()](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/add-cookie.html) - which incidentally *doesn't work* neither for me nor [someone else](http://michielve.blogspot.com/2013/04/phantomjs-cookie.html).

You can use this instead:

```
phantom.addCookie({
    'name': 'mycookie',
    'value': 'something really important',
    'domain': 'example.com'
})
page.open('http://example.com/url/path/', function() {
    console.log(page.cookies);
})
```

Comment: Why the (anonymous) downvote? This snippet shows another way to set cookies if the `WebPage.addCookie()` fails to work for some reason.

Comment: I cannot find the addCookie method in my node modules phantomjs-prebuilt, How do I get to it?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with that - I suggest you ask another question and someone else might know the answer.

Comment: but How were you able to reference the method which you are using for your answer?

Comment: It exists, follow the link in the answer: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/add-cookie.html Unfortunately I don't have enough information about your problem to help you, and I haven't touched PhantomJS in years anyway... Sorry. You really need to ask a separate question if you need help.

Comment: It does indeed but in my 2+ version I cannot see it in my node_modules, very interesting...

Answer (score 1):

The work around I had to do was to execute javascript directly. I am using Geb and did the following:

```
js.exec("document.cookie='PHPSESSID=${cookie}';")
```

When selenium fails I always fall back to javascript for functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet, but doesn't `--cookies-file=/path/to/cookies.txt` work?

It's the first item in [API](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/Interface) reference...

Comment: Yes, it writes the cookies to the specified file. but how do I get back the vale of a specific cookie?

Comment: yes... it seems that cookie support is not complete: http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=299 and http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=91

Answer (score 0):

I had graded information within session recently. You should set cookie in page object, like below (coffeescript):

```coffee
@page.clearCookies()
@page.addCookie
  'name'     : "JSESSIONID"
  'value'    : "0000rN3YAlVAU0xdHkKc6BEzWj9:-1"
  'domain'   : 'some.domain.com'
  'path'     : '/'
```