# is this testing setup correct/possible selenium IDE, ghostdriver, phantom.js, grid and php-webdriver correct?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, selenium-grid, ghostdriver

I would like to run many instances of phantomjs at once. The reason I would like to use phantomjs rather than selenium with firefox/chrome/ie is the cookie separation and the ease of using proxies if every needed (some of our systems will need to be accessed from different IP's). Plus phantomjs seems much slimmer/faster than browsers with "heads".

I would also like to generate the test scripts using selenium IDE (I've experimented with Resurrectio+casperjs its good but selenium seems better) then run them as PHP using php-webdriver.

I've been trying to understand how all these pieces fit together so is would this process work....

Generate the test scripts in selenium IDE with firefox then export them to python
Convert this Python script to a facebooks php-webdriver version. Looks like I'll have to manually do this?
Run Phantom.js with this php script and point it at the selenium java server to execute the script.

Is this all correct? Can I run multiple instances simultaneously on once machine? Will I need grid? Where does ghostdriver fit in all this!?

Comment: Seems right, but I haven't used selenium grid before, so I can't say anything about that part. Although, when running in parallel, you need to keep in mind that [localStorage is file based](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023093/does-phantomjs-store-any-persistent-files-by-default).

Comment: Ghostdriver is like a bridge between phantomJS and selenium..We just used PhantomJS in our project and for that we needed to use ghostdriver