# CasperJs do something before start?

Tags: javascript, testing, casperjs, functional-testing

I use JWTs to manage logged-in status, so I need to clear localstorage before running `casper.start`. How is this possible?

Something like:

```
casper.then(function() {
  casper.evaluate(function() {
    localStorage.clear()
  })
})

casper.start('http://localhost:3000', function() {
  test.assertUrlMatch('http://localhost:3000')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `casper.start` without any arguments to initialize the internal data and then do your stuff:

```
casper.start()
    .then(function() {
      casper.evaluate(function() {
        localStorage.clear()
      })
    })
    .thenOpen('http://localhost:3000', function() {
      test.assertUrlMatch('http://localhost:3000')
    })
```

The problem is that if you call `casper.start` without any URL, the page will stay on about:blank when you're trying to clear `localStorage`. There are basically two solutions:

- Use the `fs` module of PhantomJS to delete the localStorage database that is in the [temporary files directory for PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27023965/1816580).
- Open the target page, clear the localStorage, and open the target page again.

  ```
  var url = "...";
  casper.start(url, function() {
    this.evaluate(function() {
      localStorage.clear()
    })
  })
  .thenOpen(url, function() {
    test.assertUrlMatch('http://localhost:3000')
  })
  ```